How to get adaptive sampling to work with Application Insights and Serilog in a Dotnet6 Web API?
I'm using Application Insights version 2.22.0 and Serilog 5.1.0. I try to log 1000 iterations of a simple string (so it's the same string each time) in my HomeController Index endpoint, but all of them will arrive in AI. Why does this happen? Doesn't AI automatically use Adaptive Sampling? Or is it overriden by using Serilog? If not, how can I manually set it?
Here's my code:
appsettings.json:
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "..."
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Exceptions", "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights", 
  "{project namespace}" ],
    "Enrich": [ "WithExceptionDetails" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
        "WebOptimizer": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "logs/log.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {SourceContext} - {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "InstrumentationKey=...",
          "telemetryConverter": 
            "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
      }
    }
  ]
},

Program.cs:
private static WebApplication BuildWebApp(string[] args, IConfigurationQueries configurationQueries, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Use Castle.Windsor as dependency injection container
    var container = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();
    var serviceProviderFactory = new Castle.Windsor.Extensions.DependencyInjection.WindsorServiceProviderFactory(container);
    builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(serviceProviderFactory);
    builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer>(c => Bootstrapper.Install(c));
    builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, config) =>
    {
        config.ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration);
        config.Enrich.With(new CustomEnricher(configuration));
    });

    var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration, builder.Environment);
    startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services, configurationQueries);

    var app = builder.Build();
    startup.ConfigurePipeline(app);

    return app;
}

Startup.cs:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationQueries configurationQueries)
{
  ...
  services.ConfigureInstrumentation(_configuration, _logger);
  ...

  _logger.LogInformation($"Dependency Injection is Configured for Environment '{_environment.EnvironmentName}'.");
}

Instrumentation.cs:
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureInstrumentation(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger logger)
{
    var initializer = new InstrumentationInitializer(configuration);
    var options = initializer.CreateServiceOptions();

    services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, WebTelemetryInitializer>();
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<WebTelemetryFilter>();

    logger.LogInformation($"Application Insights was initialized with Instrumentation Key '{options.InstrumentationKey}'");
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options);

    return services;
}

CreateServiceOptions-method:
public ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions CreateServiceOptions()
{
  var instrumentationKey = _configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];

  var options = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
  {
    InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey
  };

#if DEBUG
  options.DeveloperMode = true;
  options.EnableDebugLogger = true;
#endif

  return options;
}

All trace/information log statements will be sent to AI, even though by default Adaptive Sampling should be enabled? Or is it overridden by Serilog somehow?
Can anyone tell me what I need to add to make adaptive sampling active in my project?

Are you getting any error with the above code ?


All trace/information log statements will be sent to AI, even though by default Adaptive Sampling should be enabled? Or is it overridden by Serilog somehow?

I use adaptive sampling as below:
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Serilog;

var rith = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

rith.Host.UseSerilog((cxt, ri_cf) =>
{
    ri_cf.ReadFrom.Configuration(cxt.Configuration)
          .WriteTo.Console()
          .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(
              new TelemetryConfiguration
              {
                  ConnectionString = cxt.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"] 
              },
              TelemetryConverter.Traces);
});

rith.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options =>
{
    options.EnableAdaptiveSampling = true;
});

With this i am able to use it and I also enabled adaptive sampling in application insights also.

